# How to "Gate" an Observable

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I have one Observable stream which gets ticked every time a file watcher detects that changes have occurred. This tick then results in a nested Observable kicking off to repeatedly read an open file stream until all new updates have been read, then flatten them down to the final output stream.

The problem I have, is if a change occurs to the file, kicking off the nested Observable, if this nested Observable is still reading lines from the file and hasn't completed when a second change occurs to the file, then the file watcher observable causes a SECOND nested observable to kick off, so you have two nested observables both trying to read from the same stream, which causes an InvalidOperationException - Stream is in use by another process

How can I change this Observable so that it only allows the parent Observable to create the nested observable if the previous one has completed? Ie gate the parent observable like a manual reset event, which only allows it to continue once the previous nesting completes and stops using the stream?

My code

```
    var fileSystemWatcherChanges = Observable<Unit>()

/// abbreviated for question, code here opens a file watcher to create this stream

    var outputStream = fileSystemWatcherChanges
                                        .StartWith(Unit.Default)
                                        .Select(x =>
                                            Observable
                                                .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(sr.ReadLineAsync))
                                                .Repeat()
                                                .TakeUntil(w => w == null))
                                        .Merge()
                                        .Where(w => w != null))
```

Update with Solution:

For those interested in a potential way around this, I've done some basic locking that seems to have fixed the problem. It will ignore the tick if we are currently still processing the inner observable, which I believe is satisfactory in this case because the update tick is only telling us there are more lines to read, and the currently executing ReadLine observable should pick up those new lines if they are there. We don't care about any file update triggers while we are actively processing the file stream.

```
var readingFile = 0;            
var outputStream = fileSystemWatcherChanges
    .StartWith(Unit.Default)
    .Select(delegate(Unit x)
    {
        // Deny a second file update from starting to read the stream if we are already reading it
        if (0 == Interlocked.Exchange(ref readingFile, 1))
        {
            return Observable
                .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(sr.ReadLineAsync))
                .Repeat()
                .TakeUntil(w => w == null)
                .Finally(() => Interlocked.Exchange(ref readingFile, 0));
        }

        return Observable.Empty<string>();
    })
    .Merge()
    .Where(w => w != null))
```

Comment: Try creating an `EventLoopScheduler` and use that as the second parameter for the `Observable.FromAsync(sr.ReadLineAsync)` call.

Comment: `Interlocked.Exchange` might work - and it might cause a dead-lock. Did you try the `EventLoopScheduler`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Merge` you should have used `Concat` which does subscribe to the next observable until previous is complete:

```
public static IObservable<string> ReadAsObservable<TNotification>(this TextReader reader, IObservable<TNotification> notification)
{
    return Observable.Using(() => reader,
        r =>
        {
            var readLine = Observable.FromAsync(r.ReadLineAsync);
            return notification.Select(_ => readLine.Repeat().TakeWhile(x => x != null))
                               .Concat();
        });
}
```